# Кластеризация Series

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, кластеризация

У меня не получается сделать нормально кластеризацию. Есть [датасет](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/uPJ5YvP1BsaG1A)

Выглядит он так:

```
weekday  hour
0        0       0.0
         1       0.0
         2       0.0
         3       0.0
         4       0.0
                ... 
6        19      0.0
         20      0.0
         21      0.0
         22      0.0
         23      0.0
```

Это Series с мультииндексом, где weekday- день недели, hour- час (соответственно строк 24х7). Столбец признака показывает частотную среднюю характеристику, которая получилась после группировки данных.

График выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я схематично показал, как мне надо произвести кластеризацию. Должно быть 3 кластера.
Подскажите, пожалуйста ,как это можно сделать?

Comment: А что означает на графике пары по оси Х? (0,0), (1,1).... Причем тут неделя и час?

Comment: Это мультииндекс после группировки. (0,0)- это значение частоты с 00:00:00 до 01:00:00  в понедельник, соответственно (1,13)- это значение частоты с 13:00:00 до 14:00:00 во вторник.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать кластеризовать с помощью алгоритма K-means, но в общем случае делать можно и так:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

df = pd.read_csv("friquency.csv", index_col=[0,1])
res = df.rolling(5).mean().fillna(0) # скользящее окно, размер нужно подбирать
                                     # в зависимости от желаемой толерантности

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(range(len(df)), df["Частота"])

# получаем список списков кортежей, в которых обозначены попарно координаты x
# начала и конца кластера в мультииндексе:
idx= res[res['Частота'] != 0].groupby((res['Частота'] == 0).cumsum()).apply(lambda x: list((x.index[0],x.index[-1]))).to_list()

for i in idx:
    corner = i[0][0]*24+i[0][1]-1 # -1 потому что линия на графике рисуется от
                                  # предыдущей точки
    width = i[1][0]*24+i[1][1] - corner-3 # -3 потому что отсекаем четыре последних
                                          # значения, из-за скользящего окна размером 5,
                                          # и прибавляем 1, потому что линия 
                                          # заканчивается на следующей точке.
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((corner, 0), width, df.max(), linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='r', alpha=0.2))

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Я немного пересмотрел алгоритм и решил сделать все чистыми группировками, что в данном случае позволить избежать некоторых неудобств и будет более универсальным способом:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches


df = pd.read_csv("friquency.csv", index_col=[0,1])
threshold=4 # количество 0 больше этого значения уже не будет считаться частью кластера

prep = df.copy()

# превращаем большие группы 0 в NaN для удобства дальнейшей группировки
for i, g in prep[prep['Частота'] == 0].groupby((prep['Частота'] != 0).cumsum()):
    if g.size > threshold:
        prep.loc[g.index]=np.nan

# группируем полученный сет по значениям, не равным NaN на отдельные группы
# и получаем индексы начал и концов клкстеров
clusters = prep[prep['Частота'].notnull()].groupby((prep['Частота'].isnull()).cumsum()).apply(lambda x: list((x.index[0],x.index[-1]))).to_list()
cluster_ticks = [[x[0][0]*24 + x[0][1], x[1][0]*24 + x[1][1]] for x in clusters]

# далее - визуализация и украшательство
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
plt.bar(range(len(df)), df["Частота"])

for label, i in enumerate(cluster_ticks):
    width = i[1]-i[0]
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((i[0], 0), width, df.max(), linewidth=0, edgecolor='r', facecolor='r', alpha=0.2))
    ax.plot([i[0], i[0], i[1], i[1]], [df.max()+df.max()/20, df.max()+df.max()/10, df.max()+df.max()/10, df.max()+df.max()/20], lw=0.75, c="k")
    ax.text(i[0], df.max()+df.max()/10, f"cluster {label+1}", ha='left', va='bottom', color="k")
    ax.set_xticks(np.ravel(cluster_ticks))
    ax.set_xticklabels(np.ravel([[f"{x[0][0]}d, {x[0][1]}h", f"{x[1][0]}d, {x[1][1]}h"] for x in clusters]), rotation=90)
    
plt.savefig("clusters.png")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: K-means не подойдет. Среди элементов кластеров есть нулевые. Причем ошибка даже на рисунке, представленном ТС -  в правом класере на самом деле два кластера  -  один до как минимум трех подряд нулей, второй -  после. Близко расположены, но точно разные.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш датасет мне не доступен, поэтому опишу, как я представляю решение вашей задачи.
У вас "Нормальное" состояние - это нулевые значения измеряемого параметра. Ваши "кластеры" -  это некие выбросы. Можно было бы просто считать отдельным кластером то, что отлично от 0. Проблема усложняется тем, что у вас вутри кластера тоже могут быть одиночне значения равные 0. Если это действительно так, то вот такое решение я предлагаю:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,2,3,1,3,0,2,3,4,2,0,4,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0],columns=['input'])
df.plot()

df.loc[(df.input == 0)  & (df.input.shift()!=0) & (df.input.shift(-1)!=0)]=-1
df['clusters']=0
cl_num=0
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i].input == 0:
        continue
    elif df.loc[i].input != 0:
        df.loc[i].clusters=cl_num
        if df.loc[i-1].input == 0:
            cl_num+=1
            df.loc[i].clusters=cl_num
```

Результат:

```
    input  clusters
0       0         0
1       0         0
2       0         0
3       2         1
4       3         1
5       1         1
6       3         1
7      -1         1
8       2         1
9       3         1
10      4         1
11      2         1
12     -1         1
13      4         1
14      3         1
15      0         0
16      0         0
17      0         0
18      0         0
19      0         0
20      0         0
21      1         2
22      1         2
23      2         2
24     -1         2
25      1         2
26      0         0
27      0         0
28      0         0
29      0         0
```

Столбец "clusters" и содержит метку кластера, к которому отнесено измерение.